# Let's put [preview] in the rear-view

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The tag [preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview) has an ambiguity problem. It has no tag wiki and is often misapplied in place of better, more specific tags.

For example, about half of the questions tagged with it are about Preview, the image and PDF viewer in OS X, for which there exists [preview.app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview.app). Also, the tag is applied to questions about previews of new versions of Windows and MS Office Preview, for which there are tags already.

It appears in questions about various other contexts for which a more general tag is sufficient.

This tag needs to be burned.

I suggest we go through and remove or replace the tag as appropriate for each question. The most likely replacement tags are

- [preview.app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview.app)
- [windows-10-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview)
- [windows-8.1-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8.1-preview)
- [windows-8-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview)
- [office-2013-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office-2013-preview)

Related minor tag that should also be burned:

- [print-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/print-preview): 5 questions

There are only 102 questions tagged [preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview) now, so this should be a relatively quick problem to fix.

Comment: What was it meant to be used for?

Comment: With no tag wiki, it's hard to say, but the two oldest remaining questions with the tag concern image thumbnails in Windows Explorer. The next question after that is about email previews in Outlook. It's pretty broad and inherently ambiguous, and as such, not a good tag.